# What is the effect of number of levels in levelled compaction?

Tags: cassandra, leveldb, rocksdb, scylla

I know how levelled compaction works in DBS like Cassandra, rocksdb etc. Some have max number of levels 4 and some have 7. How does this number affect compaction process? Why can't I have just 2 levels, 1st one which has flushed mem-table data (overlap possible between files) and 2nd one which contains nonoverlapping SSTs?

If there is any doc or duplicate question, please redirect.

**Edit-1:** Duplicate data increases when the number of levels goes up.

Answer (score 5):

LCS comes to solves STCS’s space-amplification problem. It also reduces read amplification (the average number of disk reads needed per read request).

Leveled compaction divides the small sstables (“fragments”) into levels:

Level 0 (L0) is the new sstables, recently flushed from memtables. As their number grows (and reads slow down), our goal is to move sstables out of this level to the next levels.
Each of the other levels, L1, L2, L3, etc., is a single run of an exponentially increasing size: L1 is a run of 10 sstables, L2 is a run of 100 sstables, L3 is a run of 1000 sstables, and so on. (Factor 10 is the default setting in both Scylla and Apache Cassandra).

While solving, or at least significantly improving, the space amplification problem, LCS makes another problem, write amplification, worse.

"Write amplification” is the amount of bytes we had to write to the disk for each one byte of newly flushed sstable data. Write amplification is always higher than 1.0 because we write each piece of data to the commit-log, and then write it again to an sstable, and then each time compaction involves this piece of data and copies it to a new sstable, that’s another write.

Read more about it here:

- https://www.scylladb.com/2018/01/31/compaction-series-leveled-compaction/
- https://docs.scylladb.com/kb/compaction/
- https://docs.scylladb.com/architecture/compaction/compaction-strategies/

Comment: I am a big fan of Scylla and it's design. I still have doubt, how we avoid space amplification when all ssts of level Ln overlaps with one (or many) of sst of Ln-1? Please correct if am missing something

Answer (score 4):

Leveled compaction works Scylla very similarly to how it works in Cassandra and Rocksdb (with some small differences). If you want a short overview on how leveled compaction works in Scylla and why, I suggest that you read my blog post https://www.scylladb.com/2018/01/31/compaction-series-leveled-compaction/.

Your specific question on why two levels (L0 of recently flushed sstables, Ln of disjoint-range sstables) are not enough - is a very good question:

The main problem is that a single flushed memtable (sstable in L0), containing a random collection of writes, will often intersect **all** of the sstables in Ln. This means rewriting the entire database every time there's a new memtable flushed, and the result is a super-huge amount of write amplification, which is completely unacceptable.

One way to reduce this write amplification significantly (but perhaps not enough) is to introduce a cascade of intermediate levels, L0, L1, ..., Ln. The end result is that we have L(n-1) which is 1/10th (say) the size of Ln, and we merge L(n-1) - not a single sstable - into Ln. This is the approach that leveled compaction strategy (LCS) uses in all systems you mentioned.

A completely different approach could be not to merge a single sstable into Ln, but rather try to collect a large amount of data first, and only then merge it into Ln. We can't just collect 1,000 tables in L0 because this would make reads very slow. Rather, to collect this large amount of data, one could use size-tiered compaction (STCS) inside L0. In other words, this approach is a "mix" of STCS and LCS with two "levels": L0 uses STCS on new sstables, Ln contains a run of sstables (sstables with disjoint ranges). When L0 reaches 1/10th (say) the size of Ln, L0 is compacted into Ln. Such a mixed approach could have lower write amplification than LCS, but because most of the data is in a run in Ln, it would have same low space and read amplifications as in LCS. None of the mentioned databases (Scylla, Cassandra, or Rocksdb) has such "mixed" compaction supported, as far as I know.

Comment: Have read all (possibly) documents related to compaction. I do understand the problem of having just two level, intersection of L0 tables might include all tables of L1, which is nothing but writing entire db. As per my understanding, the last level Ln will have all data (ssts) after many compaction and when a compaction runs for Ln-1 level which finds overlap in Ln which possibly can include lot more ssts. If I just pick one sst from Ln-1, there is a possibility of overlap of all ssts of Ln, which is again same writing almost entire db. Hope I am making sense, please correct